# akka split task into smaller and fold results

Tags: scala, akka, actor

The question is about **Akka actors** library. A want to split one big task into smaller tasks and then fold the result of them into one 'big' result. This will give me faster computation profit. Smaller tasks can be computed in parallel if they are independent.

Assume that we need to compute somethig like this. Function `count2X` is time consuming, so using it several times in one thread is not optimal.

```
//NOT OPTIMAL
def count2X(x: Int) = {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  x * 2
}

val sum = count2X(1) + count2X(2) + count2X(3)
println(sum)
```

And here goes the question.

**How to dispatch tasks and collect results and then fold them, all using akka actors?**
Is such functionality already provided by Akka or do I need to implement it myself? What are best practisies in such approach.

Here is 'visual' interpretation of my question:

```
             /-> [SMALL_TASK_1] -\
[BIG_TASK] -+--> [SMALL_TASK_1] --> [RESULT_FOLD]
             \-> [SMALL_TASK_1] -/
```

Below is my scaffold implementation with missing/bad implementation :)

```
case class Count2X(x: Int)

class Count2XActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Count2X(x) => count2X(x); // AND NOW WHAT ?
  }
}

case class CountSumOf2X(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)

class SumOf2XActor extends Actor {
  val aCounter = context.actorOf(Props[Count2XActor])
  val bCounter = context.actorOf(Props[Count2XActor])
  val cCounter = context.actorOf(Props[Count2XActor])

  def receive = {
    case CountSumOf2X(a, b, c) => // AND NOW WHAT ? aCounter ! Count2X(a); bCounter ! Count2X(b); cCounter ! Count2X(c);
  }
}

val aSystem = ActorSystem("mySystem")
val actor = aSystem.actorOf(Props[SumOf2XActor])

actor ! CountSumOf2X(10, 20, 30)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you considered using Scala's parallel collections for this? no Akka actors (visibly) involved, but then it's just map and fold: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Akka I would do something like this:

```
val a = aCounter ? Count2X(10) mapTo[Int]
val b = bCounter ? Count2X(10) mapTo[Int]
val c = cCounter ? Count2X(10) mapTo[Int]
Await.result(Future.sequence(a, b, c) map (_.sum), 1 second).asInstanceOf[Int]
```

I'm sure there is a better way - here you start summing results after all `Future`-s are complete in parallel, for simple task it's ok, but generally you shouldn't wait so long

Answer (score 2):

Two things you could do:

1) Use Akka futures. These allow you to dispatch operations and fold on them in an asynchronous manner. Check out http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.4/scala/futures.html for more information.

2) You can dispatch work to multiple "worker" actors and then have a "master" actor aggregate them, keeping track of which messages are pending/processed by storing information in the messages themselves. I have a simple stock quote example of this using Akka actors here: https://github.com/ryanlecompte/quotes

Comment: +1 for futures.  Given what you've told us about the problem Futures seem like the simplest solution.